# how create a collection of models from array with their IDs - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I am creating a foreach loop with button `attach (name)' for each model which is not connected to the base model with a`belongsToMany` relation.

I have an array with IDs for a certain model

```
$attached_stages = $object->stages()->getRelatedIds()->toArray(); // output: 1, 2
```

Then I have all model instances for the same model,

```
$all_stages = Stage::orderBy('id', 'asc')->pluck('id')->all(); // output: 1,2,3,4 ... 6

$missing_stages = array_diff($all_stages, $attached_stages); // output: 3,4,5,6
```

### My question: how to get a collection out of the `$missing_stages` array

The array is created as expected

### My question (alternative solution)

What I am actually trying to get here is a collection of models which are not attached to the main `$object` with the `stages()` relation.

The relation is defined as follows:

```
public function stages()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Stage', 'lead_stage', 'lead_id', 'stage_id')->withPivot('id','status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and I am unable to get my desired collection with this code:

```
    $all_stages = Stage::get(); //  output: collction 1,2,.... 6
    $attached_stages = $object->stages(); // output: 1, 2  
    $missing_stages = $all_stages->diff($attached_stages); // expected output:  3,4,5,6
```

Note: I attempted to remove the pivot part in relation definition, but it didn't help, the `diff` method is not working for me. Nothing is cut from the collection.

Any help appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`whereNotIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) for your problem as:

```
$attached_stages = $object->stages()->getRelatedIds()->toArray();

$missing_stages = Stage::whereNotIn('id', $attached_stages)->get();
```

Comment: I can use some more coffee too, it seems. Thank you.